# Warn when returning const copy of object

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-warnings

Look at the function declarations below:

```
int Foo();        // [1] Ok
const int &Foo(); // [2] Ok
const int Foo();  // [3] Not Ok. Same as [1]. Compiler can warn.

Bar Foo();        // [4] Ok
const Bar &Foo(); // [5] Ok
const Bar Foo();  // [6] Ok, not same as [4] or [5], but more likely a typo then intended design.
```

**Is it possible to ask Clang and/or GCC to warn about [6]?**

I know this is legal, but I don't think it is very useful. I am pretty sure that all declarations like this in our code base are typos, and I would like to detect those at compile time.

**Update:**
It seems to be some confusion about the const copy in [6]. Here is example of how little protection this is. Relying on the calling code not to make a copy is a large flaw in the design. Its is not robust at all. My question still stands, *how can I get a warning about this*, not what should I do when I receive the warning. Maybe I'll just ignore it :)

**[Live demo](http://cpp.sh/7ey7u)**

Comment: 3 and 5 have the same relationship as 1 and the "Not Ok." line.  It'd be a bit easeir if you gave each line its own number..

Comment: Fixed the line number. No, the relation is not the same since int is a basic type and Bar is a class.

Comment: `const` applies equally to both

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with Bar. If it is some sort of ill-conceived container where modifying the returned copy also modifies the source you're in for a world of hurt removing the const and allowing modification.

Comment: Then you should fix the constainer. The calling code can anyway just make non-const copy on his side.

Comment: @M.M "const applies equally to both". Probably true, but const is meaningless for basic types as they don't have methods. Removing the const can not make any difference, hence the compiler can warn. As noted by others, the same does not apply to removing the const from class copies.

Comment: perhaps you could grep your code for `const` followed by `(` without `&` in between

Comment: This will be part of a continuous integration build. Tool chain is; gcc, clang, scan-build. Grepping is not robust. An option is to write a clang pluging to add my own warnig, but I rather not :)

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense for many types of object and can crop up when a template type expands to const.  For a class object, the difference between a comst and a non-const object can be far from trivial!  Consider the difference between returning a const and non-const copy of, for example, an object containing getters and setters for global data.  If `const`, it can only get.  If not ….

Keep in mind this is protection against shooting yourself in the foot, not against deliberately circumventing the type system.  It’s possible to write to const references too, but you explicitly don’t consider those a kind of typo.

Comment: I know the difference between const and non-const, but here you return a copy.. Why care whether the calling code modifies the copy, it is not yours anyway. You can not possibly know what the caller wants with the copy. The only reason to force the copy to be const would be to try to "help" the caller. But it is hard to help when you don't now the use case. If the caller wants a const copy he can just make it const him selves.

Comment: Because when the object contains references to shared data, and non-const copies can modify that shared data, you can do things through a non-const copy that you can’t do through a const copy.

Comment: But then you could copy the object to a non const object and still do things.

Comment: Correct. It tells the compiler to prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot. It does not make it safe for a library to pass the copy to malicious code.

Comment: Updated question with example code. I would not consider line 33-35 in example to be malicious code.